# Puppeteer: Clicking on a link that updates an element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape data from a website's table with Puppeteer. However, when the table has more than a 100 entries, it splits it across multiple tables and has arrows to navigate. After I scrape all the information from the first 100 entries on the table page 1, I want to click the next arrow ">>" and go to the next 100 entries to scrape them, and so on. But the ">>" arrow, when clicked in a regular browser, doesn't lead to a new page, and simply updates the contents of the same table.

I inspected the HTML and see that the ">>" button is wrapped in

`<a href="/DailyReport?page=2" rel="next">`

I tried getting the  element and clicking on it:

```
const nextButton = await page.$('ul.wrapper > li > a[rel=next]');
await nextButton.click();
await page.waitForSelector('.dataTable');
```

... but this doesn't work. I confirmed that `nextButton` was the element that I wanted to fetch by logging the outerHTML.

I also tried just

```
await page.goto('www.originaldomain.com/DailyReport?page=2')
```

but this doesn't work because this tries to load a new page with that URL (isn't found), instead of just updating the one `dataTable` element.

It seems like under normal usage, routing to `/DailyReport?page=2` triggers some JavaScript to update the table elements. How do I replicate this clicking of the 'next page' button to update the table using puppeteer?

EDIT: Typo from `waitForElement(...)` to `waitForSelector(...)`

Comment: Hi,
I would suggest testing it with headless:false in order to really see what is going on.
I also would have tried with `await page.waitForSelector('.dataTable');` **(I guess you meant waitForSelector and not waitForElement, right?)**.  Are you sure that there is no other element with the class `.dataTable`?
Also, you can maybe just add a 'wait' for a few seconds: `await page.waitFor(2000)`.

Comment: @charlyrl yes, I did mean waitForSelector. I will try out your suggestions. Thank you!